# Firefox NSS Library Directory location (windows)

Tags: java, windows, applet, nss

I`m using java applet and i need authenticate user choosing digital certificate from usb token.
I don't know how to determine nssLibraryDirectory.
Currently i use location to nss3.dll from Mozilla Firefox and i get this error: is not a valid Win32 application.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: DO you have some code to show?

Comment: Hi, Robin this is part of my code,

// PKCS11
            signer = new PKCS11Signer(); 
            Properties signerProps = new Properties();
            
            signerProps.setProperty(PKCS11Signer.PKCS11_NAME, "NSSkeystore");
          
         signerProps.setProperty(PKCS11Signer.KEY_ACCESS_NEEDED, "false");
         
           signerProps.setProperty(PKCS11Signer.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD_NEEDED, "false");
            
 // location for nss3.dll          
           signerProps.setProperty("nssLibraryDirectory", "C:\\Users\\PETKO\\Desktop\\nss-3.17.3");

Comment: The problem was in java jdk i use 64 bit jdk instead 32 bit but i have new error 
java.security.ProviderException: Could not initialize NSS
 at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:212)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:107)
 at sample.applet.PKCS11Signer.setProperties(PKCS11Signer.java:104)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The specified module could not be found.